# Hibernate changing my field name

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am practice Hibernate with the following classes and a MySQL database.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int student_id;

    private String student_name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private StudentAddress address;

    @Transient
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date birthDay;

    public Student() {
    }

    public Date getBirthDay() {
        return birthDay;
    }

    public void setBirthDay(Date birthDay) {
        this.birthDay = birthDay;
    }

    public int getStudent_id() {
        return student_id;
    }

    public void setStudent_id(int rollNo) {
        this.student_id = rollNo;
    }

    public String getStudent_name() {
        return student_name;
    }

    public void setStudent_name(String name) {
        this.student_name = name;
    }

    public StudentAddress getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(StudentAddress address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name="student_address")
public class StudentAddress {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int address_id;

    private String address_detail;

    public int getAddress_id() {
        return address_id;
    }

    public void setAddress_id(int address_id) {
        this.address_id = address_id;
    }

    public String getAddress_detail() {
        return address_detail;
    }

    public void setAddress_detail(String address_detail) {
        this.address_detail = address_detail;
    }
}
```

I keep getting the following error message from these sql statements:

```
Hibernate: insert into student_address (address_detail) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into Student (address_address_id, student_name) values (?, ?)
```

Error Message:

```
Unknown column '**address_address_id'** in 'field list'
```

My database has the field name `address_id`.

Hibernate keeps appending `address` to `address_id` and changes the column name. I could probably change the field name from `address` to `address_address_id` in my database but what is causing this to happen. Is it a valid behavior in Hibernate and can I change it?

Answer (score 2):

That's the [default column name](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#name--) Hibernate uses for `@ManyToOne` association:

> Default (only applies if a single join column is used): The
>   concatenation of the following: the name of the referencing
>   relationship property or field of the referencing entity or embeddable
>   class; "_"; the name of the referenced primary key column. If there is
>   no such referencing relationship property or field in the entity, or
>   if the join is for an element collection, the join column name is
>   formed as the concatenation of the following: the name of the entity;
>   "_"; the name of the referenced primary key column.

To specify the desired column name:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="address")
private StudentAddress address;
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Thanks a lot. I wasted about 1.5 hours trying to figure it out.